# Looping a print function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

If the value for qtytxt is 4. It produces this on 1 print page.

[image]

This is the code that does so.

```
 report = "";
    for (i = 0; i < document.getElementById("qtytxt").value; i++) {
    report += "ID: " + document.getElementById("generateidtxt").value + "-" + (i + 1) + "<br>";
    }
    document.write(report);
    window.print();
```

Is there a way I can make an array or another loop so that I can get the result for the first ID to be printed on a separate page, then the 2nd ID to be printed on a new page, and so on? So if the value of qtytxt was 6 it will produce 6 id's with the numbers 1-6 at the end. I want each ID to prompt me to print on it's own separate page for a total of 6 pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is something like this what you are looking for?

```
report = "";
var max = document.getElementById("qtytxt").value;
for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    report += "ID: " + 
        document.getElementById("generateidtxt").value + 
        "-" + 
        (i + 1) + 
        (i < (max - 1) ?
        "<div style='page-break-after:always'></div>" : "");
}
document.write(report);
window.print();
```

Comment: It splits the ID's into several pages which is good, but it also creates a blank page after the last ID. Is there a way I can get rid of that blank page as well?

Comment: You can try setting it to `page-break-after:auto` or strip the last div. See my updates.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the [`page-break-before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-before) attribute would be of benefit here? You could make a new element before every page that isn't the first one, with this attribute.